# GET form action. Redirect to self

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm writing filter for posts by category on author page.

I send category name in $_GET array in this form:

```
<form action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get" id="form1">
      <select name="type" class="form-select" id="edit-type">
           <option value="all">All</option>
           <option value="articles">Article</option>
           <option value="posts">Blog Post</option>
       </select>
       <input type="submit" value="Apply" class="form-submit">
</form>
```

For exapmle I have link `www.mysite.com/?author=8`. If I type link `www.mysite.com/?author=8&type=posts`, all works correct, but if I use form, I'm redirect to home page just with parameter 'type' `www.mysite.com/?type=posts`

Also, I try to use in form action current page url, porblem is the same.

How can I send get parameter and redirect to slef page?

I'm use wordpress 3.8. Thanks. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="authour" id="authour"  value="<?php the_author_ID(); ?>"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

make your author as hidden field inside the form and pass it

```
<input type="hidden" name="newauthour" id="newauthour"  value="8"/>
```